# Get meetings by organizer or attendee email ID using GoToMeeting SDK

Tags: sdk, citrix, organizer

I am using .`Net sdk of GoToMeeting`.

I want to get meetings organized by particular organizer.
I have tried using 
`MeetingsApi.getHistoryMeetings` but it does not return me `OrganizerKey` so I can not filter on particular Organizer.

Is there any way to get meeting(s) based on organizer or even by Attendee email ID by using .Net `SDK`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing with `MeetingsApi.getHistoryMeetings();`?

why you need to filter the method, the `MeetingsApi.getHistoryMeetings(accessToken,true,date1,date2);` itself filtered for a particular user right?

Look on the **arguments** we are passing in the method?

1. **accessToken** - This token is generated as a result of successful authentication of a gotoproduct account. (In API call it can be generated using `directlogin` or`Oauth` method.
2. **true** - this represents whether the meetings returned are past or not.
3. **date1** - Start date range for the meetings.
4. **date2** - End date range for the meetings.

below code is the sample for getting history meetings.

```
DateTime sdt=DateTime.Parse("07/01/2015");
DateTime edt=DateTime.Parse("07/30/2015");
List<MeetingHistory> historymeets = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MeetingHistory>();
historymeets=meeting.getHistoryMeetings(accesToken, true, sdt, edt);
foreach (var item in historymeets)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.subject);
}
```

try it out... The above code will store the meetings in `historymeets` collection object.

You can do the filter function in that collection object.

**UPDATE :**

```
List<MeetingHistory> historymeets = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MeetingHistory>();
historymeets=meeting.getHistoryMeetings(accesToken, true, sdt, edt);
List<AttendeeByMeeting> lstAttendee = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AttendeeByMeeting>();
foreach (var item in historymeets)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.meetingId);
  lstAttendee=meeting.getAttendeesByMeetings(accesToken, item.meetingId);
  foreach (var itemattendee in lstAttendee)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(itemattendee.attendeeEmail);
  }
}
```

for comment - It is possible, but not directly because there is no api calls, which supports the `meeting by attendee` . the above code which i have written is for `meeting by organizer` . Now you have two options,

1. get the `getHistoryMeetings`, now you got the meeting details right? , then get the attendees by meeting id using `getAttendeesByMeetings()`, filter the two different collection objects with `join` using **LINQ**. OR
2. get the meetingdetails and attendees by executing two different fuinction calls, and store it in database or somewhere else, so that you can access it for doing the filter

Comment: Yes by using MeetingsApi.getHistoryMeetings(), I will get meeting created by particular user, But I want to filter further on Attendee email ID. Like I have one attendee with emailID "abc@test.com" then I want to filter on it and get only those meetings in which "abc@test.com" is attendee.

Comment: @SagarJoshi Updated the post, start from update, hope you got it.